# gRPC-Core Apple Mach-O Linker Error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods, swift4

I am using cocoapods to download the following pods

```
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
pod 'Moscapsule', :git => 'https://github.com/flightonary/Moscapsule.git'
pod 'OpenSSL-Universal'
```

When I load up the workspace in xCode 9.1 Beta and compile, I get errors with the gRPC-Core pod. What are these errors and how do I get rid of them.

[image]

Comment: gRPC builds fine for me if I remove the Moscapsule and OpenSSL-Universal pods from the Podfile. I suspect something about OpenSSL-Universal is causing a problem.

Comment: I have confirmed this as well. While I have no solution for using Moscapsule, using EmmetMQTT instead will get rid of the issue. They both have similar functionality.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue on xcode 9.0.1 beta.

After setting the xcode's ios deployment target from 11.0 to 10.0, i can build successfully.

Comment: Worked for me on Xcode 9.1 by changing deployment target from 9.0 to 10.0 in Project's Target settings as well as setting platform :ios, '10.0' in Podfile.